# Dropbox SDK for iOS: [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error reading stored credentials (-25308)

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

Everything goes well in iOS Simulator， but I run it in my iPod touch5，it got warning at first: `[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error reading stored credentials (-25308)` .

And I link Dropbox like this:

`- (IBAction)didPressLink {
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    } else {
    //enter explorer view controller.
    }
}`

in explorer view controller I list all files of root like this:

`[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];`

Only see any error return.

The app running log here:

`2014-04-09 12:21:44.870 WebDisk[17838:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error reading stored credentials (-25308)
2014-04-09 12:21:46.683 WebDisk[17838:907] -[DropBoxAdapter isLinked] line:70 unlink dropbox
2014-04-09 12:21:46.687 WebDisk[17838:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error deleting credentials (-25308)
2014-04-09 12:21:53.517 WebDisk[17838:907] Received memory warning.
//some log useless
2014-04-09 12:23:29.717 WebDisk[17838:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error reading stored credentials (-25308)
2014-04-09 12:23:29.721 WebDisk[17838:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error saving credentials (-25308)
2014-04-09 12:23:29.723 WebDisk[17838:907] Dropbox linked successfully!
2014-04-09 12:23:29.724 WebDisk[17838:907] -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] line:57 url = db-bgdebclfjdbafzt://1/connect?oauth_token=lmwh8uvm5s15mtpz&oauth_token_secret=ll0vkcz6b1xxclx&uid=283147016&state=6BCFD0EC-BD8D-4E5F-8029-2BE5E8239969
source = com.getdropbox.Dropbox
annotation=(null)
2014-04-09 12:23:33.776 WebDisk[17838:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/auto - (403) Parameter not found: oauth_token
2014-04-09 12:23:33.782 WebDisk[17838:907] -[ExplorerViewController webDiskClient:loadMetadataFailedWithError:] line:274 Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)" UserInfo=0x1e8ddc70 {path=/, error=Parameter not found: oauth_token}`

Comment: I believe this should correspond to errSecInteractionNotAllowed  from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html . This should work out of the box, so is there any reason you might be having keychain issues on this device? (E.g., jailbroken, code signing issues, etc.)

Comment: It's really a jailbroken device. But I don't know why. And, any other problem it is for jailbroken device？